# pasar matriz php a tabla html

Tags: php, html

Me estoy iniciando en PHP y me han mandado crear una tabla desde una matriz, que es la siguiente:

```
$array_notas=array(
            "Matemáticas"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>3,"Segundo trimestre"=>10,"Tercer trimestre"=>7),
            "Lengua"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>8,"Segundo trimestre"=>5,"Tercer trimestre"=>3),
            "Física"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>7,"Segundo trimestre"=>2,"Tercer trimestre"=>1),
            "Latín"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>4,"Segundo trimestre"=>7,"Tercer trimestre"=>8),
            "Ingles"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>6,"Segundo trimestre"=>2,"Tercer trimestre"=>3)
        );
```

He probado varias cosas, pero todas me salen mal, ya que necesito sacar cualquier celda del array con los bucles foreach, y ahí ya me lio.
Probé con esto pero no me muestra las notas:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Actividad 1</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#66CCFF"><center>
    <hr><h1>Boletín de notas</h1><hr>
    <?php
        $array_notas=array(
            "Matemáticas"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>3,"Segundo trimestre"=>10,"Tercer trimestre"=>7),
            "Lengua"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>8,"Segundo trimestre"=>5,"Tercer trimestre"=>3),
            "Física"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>7,"Segundo trimestre"=>2,"Tercer trimestre"=>1),
            "Latín"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>4,"Segundo trimestre"=>7,"Tercer trimestre"=>8),
            "Ingles"=>array("Primer trimestre"=>6,"Segundo trimestre"=>2,"Tercer trimestre"=>3)
        );
        ?>
        <table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td width=100 align="center"><b>Asignaturas</b></td>
        <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 1</b></td>
        <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 2</b></td>
        <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 3</b></td>
        <td width=100 align="center"><b>Media</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$array_notas[0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][2].'</td>
        <td align="right">6.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$array_notas[1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[1][0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[1][1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[1][2].'</td>
        <td align="right">5.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$array_notas[2].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[2][0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[2][1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[2][2].'</td>
        <td align="right">3.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$array_notas[3].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[3][0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[3][1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[3][2].'</td>
        <td align="right">6.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$array_notas[4].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[4][0].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[4][1].'</td>
        <td align="right">'.$array_notas[4][2].'</td>
        <td align="right">3.7</td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        <p><h3><b>La media total es 5.1</b></h3>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner alguno de los ejemplos que hayas intentado y explicar qué problema te daba?

Comment: @SJuan76 he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera parte de la tabla es correcta. Defines los titulos de cada columna.

En la siguiente parte,

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">'.$array_notas[0].'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][0].'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][1].'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$array_notas[0][2].'</td>
    <td align="right">6.7</td>
</tr>
```

Es donde estan los problemas.

1.- la primera columna es el titulo de la asignatura. En el array que defines, es la "clave" del primer elemento. Esto es:

```
array_keys($array_notas)[0];
```

2.- cada asignatura, a su vez, tiene una clave y su valor. Por ejemplo, para la segunda columna, la clave es `Primer trimestre` y su valor es `3`. Para acceder a su valor, tienes que hacer:

```
$array_notas[0]['Primer trimestre'];
```

3.- para las siguientes asignaturas, `cambia la clave anterior`.

4.- para los siguientes elementos, lo que tienes que cambiar es el `primer indice`. es decir, la segunda fila sera con indice 1.

Por ultimo, dado que tienes un array definido con varios elementos, lo normal es recorrer el array fila a fila, e ir escribiendo los datos con las variables correspondientes. Esto te lo dejo a ti (se ve que es cosa de estudio, asi que revisa la parte de bucles para ello).

Comment: y hay alguna manera de recorrer toda la matriz, como tu dices, incluso el encabezado, con dos bucles for? estoy un poco pez por favor y los apuntes no son nada buenos

Comment: con el encabezado no. pero lo que son los items si. busca `foreach` en tus apuntes.

Comment: podría ser así, pero también me da errores:
    '<tr>
     <td width=100 align="center"><b>Asignaturas</b></td>
     <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 1</b></td>
     <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 2</b></td>
     <td width=100 align="center"><b>Trimestre 3</b></td>
     <td width=100 align="center"><b>Media</b></td>
    </tr>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($array_notas);$i++){
       echo '<tr>';
     foreach($array_notas[$i]as $key=>$valor){
      echo '<td>'.$array_notas[$i][$valor].'</td>';
     }
     echo '</tr>';
    }'

Comment: no aplicas bien el foreach. Te pongo una solucion:        foreach($array_notas as $asignatura => $trimestres) {
          echo "<tr><td>".$asignatura."</td>"; 
            foreach($trimestres as $trimestre => $nota) {
                echo "<td>".$nota."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

Comment: Gracias @Jakala, ahora si me sale bien